# Sequences of composition factors in composition series

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose

$\bullet$ $M$ is a left $R$-module which is both artinian and noetherian,

$\bullet$ $C_1,\ldots,C_k$ is a list of the compositions factors of a composition series of $M$ listed up to isomorphism without repetition,

$\bullet$ $c_i$ is the number of compositions factors isomorphic to $C_i$ in a composition series of $M$.

Question:

Is there, for any sequence $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ where $$X_i \in \{C_1,\ldots,C_k\} \hbox{ and } \lvert \{X_j : X_j = C_i\} \rvert = c_i,$$
a compositions series of $M$, $$0 = M_0 < M_1 < \ldots < M_n = M,$$
such that $M_i / M_{i-1} \cong X_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$?

Answer (score 2):

Not in general.  You may be interested in looking up uniserial modules.  These are modules that have only one composition series so the sequence of $X_i$'s is uniquely determined.